# How to fix the error "can't convert expression to float"

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

Its a simple line of code but still I can't figure out why its giving such an error "can't convert expression to float"

```
from __future__ import division
from pylab import *
from sympy import *
r = symbols('r')
P = 1023732.58489791*cos(r) + 355250.305250305*cos(2*r)
P1 = solve(P,r)
print P1
```

#### Errors Image is attached here:

[Error message snapshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9-2EbFYSifES21sZ0E3dVExLVE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Where does `r` come from?

Comment: Can you please include the *full* traceback for the error?

Comment: Sorry, I missed something, now edited...